# App crashes randomly while playing video in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to display videos from youtube. Sometimes the app crashes while loading the video. Here is the error that gets displayed:

```
014-08-05 20:07:37.696 Winnin[8182:60b] <NSMutableURLRequest: 0xb6b27a0> { URL:  }
2014-08-05 20:07:37.697 Winnin[8182:60b] start
2014-08-05 20:07:37.858 Winnin[8182:60b] <NSMutableURLRequest: 0xb6b05d0> { URL: about:blank }
2014-08-05 20:07:37.859 Winnin[8182:60b] start
2014-08-05 20:07:38.442 Winnin[8182:60b] <NSMutableURLRequest: 0xb6b05d0> { URL: about:blank }
2014-08-05 20:07:38.442 Winnin[8182:60b] start
2014-08-05 20:07:46.422 Winnin[8182:60b] setting movie path: http://r1---sn-905qg5ou-qxae.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=o-APKbhANmPifVtRwbQQ-7NGPp3ZVZeJmL2bsPTnbBj5Nh&ipbits=0&expire=1407271064&sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mt=1407249329&mws=yes&mm=31&signature=341C698338B597434FA59ADE4092816FA9070AE8.65FB85A2571B750650EAD95259E90663FC86A76C&upn=SrMR9Vc4ZZA&itag=18&ip=202.164.45.66&key=yt5&fexp=902408%2C902547%2C917000%2C927622%2C929203%2C931983%2C934024%2C934030%2C937431%2C938000%2C941429%2C945066%2C946013%2C948111%2C948506&ratebypass=yes&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&sver=3&cpn=-ic4ioUmuivhjjZT&ptk=FunnyFuse&oid=sZVZBp4d_QZnKLy4m9NwoQ&ptchn=_zEzzq54Rm0iy7lmmZbCIg&pltype=content&c=web&cver=html5
2014-08-05 20:07:47.159 Winnin[8182:6203] RTCReporting: resolve from http://pancake.apple.com/bags/hls?version=4.12
```

I don't have any idea that why it is happening.

I am in a hurry so any kind of help on this will be very helpful.

Comment: What does the stack trace (crash log) look like when the app crashes?

Comment: Can you actually stream that video successfully in Safari or another youtube player application from your device, within your organisation. That should identify whether it's a proxy issue.

Comment: Yes I can play the video outside of my application but from within the application it is not. The app crashes.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any resolution here?

Comment: I have not found any solution yet

Comment: Am also having this problem on 2014 end. And, the OP didnt get answer even he post since 2011.